# Where is the Next Backup Size entry on iOS 12?

Tags: iphone, ios

I briefly saw the `Next Backup Size` entry on my phone deep in the Settings somewhere, but not I cannot find it at all.

Where exactly is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings → Apple ID → iCloud → Manage Storage → Backups → This iPhone/iPad.

This location is documented at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247 in the section titled **Choose which apps to back up** but doesn’t spell out the next size calculation.

Comment: Pretty buried down a rabbit hole, TBH

Comment: @bmike I don’t see a mention of the backup size calculation documented at that link under the section mentioned, only a mention of turning apps on and off for backup?

Comment: Holy smokes.  You have to be an archeologist to find it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: It documents the tap tap and the change from iOS 10.2 and 10.3 that changed where to find this handy tidbit, though.

Comment: @bmike Ah that’s a useful little piece of information!